# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin UWP break, unable to load "sqlite3"

Tags: xamarin, sqlite, uwp, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

When I launch UWP project, it crashes and I'm getting errors like these.
And this error occurs mostly when its on debugging mode.

[image]

Soo.. first idea for fixing this was upgrading/downgrading nuggets, but that didn't help me, also I have these nuggets included for UWP:

1. Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform
2. SQLite.Net-PCL
3. System.Data.SQLite
4. Xamarin.Forms
5. XLabs.Forms
   etc other(that dosent matter on this exception)

[image]
[image]

I also looked other posts for solving this, like adding SQLite extension, but I didnt find the extension from Universal Windows->Extensions.

[image]

Im pretty stuck with this problem, I think its probably a problem with nuggets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were fairly close. Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates. Click the Online tab in the left hand menu.

Search for SQLite and download SQLite for Universal Windows Platform.

Now go back to the Extensions window, as you showed above, and tick the SQLite for Universal Windows Platform. Ensure you keep the Visual C++ 2015 Runtime ticked, you need this as well.