# Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll' on Visual Studio 2017 for UWP project

Tags: sqlite, uwp, visual-studio-2017, xaf

I get this error when using SQLite.

> DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

I tried several solution without success.

Tried using x86/x64

Tried this:
[Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin UWP break, unable to load "sqlite3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667943/visual-studio-2017-xamarin-uwp-break-unable-to-load-sqlite3)

Added 2015 Visual C++ runtime dependency for UWP.

Tried manually adding the .dll and set it to "copy always".

Tried installing locally depedencies from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: Could you share detail about the nuget package you have used?

Comment: Ended up using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases guide (and came up with other issues but finally worked). I was trying to use System.Data.SQLite without success.

Comment: Yep, [`System.Data.SQLite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/1.0.106)does not support for uwp.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running in release but not in debug.
I am using VS2017 15.9.5
Using Release manager I changed all the projects to use Release x64 
Strangely the Platform tab asked me to make a new Platform and I had to do this in order to be able to pick an x64 platform
[image: change platform]

I wound up installing the SQLite modules in all the projects, not just the data tier. it would not work with just the data tier, even though I had Copy local true.

Here are the nuget packages I used

[image: nuget packages]

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T674595/model-editor-doesn-t-work-with-build-target-x64